# If the user has already set my app as HomeScreen, is there an easy way to switch the Home Activity?

Tags: java, android, homescreen

I am making an app, but there are basically two different, albeit similar Home Screens. There is the one Home Screen designated for personal use, and the other one distinctly for business use. Both Home Screens are launchers from which you can launch the apps that correspond to that Home Screen.

Now I set my Home Screen this way:

```
ComponentName component = new ComponentName(HomeScreen1.class.getPackage().getName(), HomeScreen1.class.getName());
packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(component, packageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
startActivity(intent);
```

When I launched a personal app and then press Home, I want it to go to the personal apps Home Screen, when I am on the business Home Screen (it's just a different activity you can get to by pushing a button on the first Home Screen), if I launch a business app, I want pressing Home to bring me to this second Home Screen.

I realize that one way to do this is to just have one Home Screen activity and kind of change the `setContentView()` arguments so that it visually changes, but this becomes very unmanageable. Since the user has nominated my app as a Home Screen Replacement App, even though technically only one Activity is nominated as the Home Screen, I was wondering if there was a way to, when the user presses the Home button go through some control statement and launch one of the two Home Screens?

It need not necessarily be that simple a solution, but basically I'm trying to avoid constantly overriding the `setContentView()` method, if possible.

EDIT: In case it's unclear, I have `HomeScreenPersonal` and `HomeScreenBusiness`, currently pressing Home button always brings you to `HomeScreenPersonal`. I was wondering if there was a way to easily have 2 home screens basically where the Home Screen is dependent on some high level boolean.

Comment: Let say the user chooses HomeScreenPersonal, should it always go to HomeScreenPersonal after that?

Comment: They are two distinct activities, with a `GridView` of apps. At the bottom of each is a button that takes you to the other screen. If you launch an app from Personal, when you press Home I want you back in Personal. If you launch an app from Business, when you press Home I want you back in Business. Currently no matter what you launch you are brought back to Personal, since that's the "main home" activity of my entire app.

Comment: I suppose the best bet might be to create a different Home Activity whose onCreate() is if(personal) intent = Personal; else intent = Business

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an interesting and functional way to get the behavior I want. Basically create only one `HomeScreen` with:

```
public static boolean personalMain = true;

private Activity activity = this;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (personalMain) {
        new HomeScreenPersonal(activity);
    } else {
        new HomeScreenBusiness(activity);
    }
}
```

Then instead of having those two be `Activity` objects, just make them regular classes whose constructors specify the `setContentView()`. Fairly clean way of having multiple Home Screens.

Answer (score 0):

You  can use SharedPreference to store any app wide variables (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Here is an example on how to use SharedPreferences (http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html).

If you want to give your user more options (ie changing the home screen), you may want to create a Settings activity as recommended by this guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html.

Comment: This isn't really what I'm looking for, there are a few ways to create high level booleans, either using `SharedPreferences` or a `static` from some class. What I want is to be able to take that boolean and change which activity is the Home Screen. When you make your app a Home Screen replacement, by default, only one activity is associated with the Home Screen.